# cx_Freeze No module named 'Tkinter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Currently when I use cx_freeze to build my python script, it runs the build and creates it, but when you go to run the exe it comes up with the below error...

[image: error]

My setup.py script looks like the below...

[image]

After the setup.py has run it creates the below files along with the exe...

[image]

When you run the MOSIEwin.exe I get the above error, I really do not understand as to why its not finding Tkinter as it looks to be importing it in the package?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60619203/cx-freeze-error-module-not-found-tkinter). Essentially, you can drop down into ./lib and rename "Tkinter" to "tkinter". It has also been addressed in the cx_freeze issue tracker [here](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/567).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I got this working doing the above 